# Same d3.js Is throwing Invalid Charecter Error

Tags: d3.js

js I just downloaded d3.js and included in cubism example It worked and the same d3.js is giving invalid charecter error when I tried to load reel example through IIS.

Below is the error at which it is throwing error.
I agree there are some special charecters in this line but it is handeled in [cubism exaple](http://square.github.com/cubism/) but why not in [showreel](http://bl.ocks.org/1256572) ?

```
var sinφ0 = Math.sin(φ0), n = (sinφ0 + Math.sin(φ1)) / 2, C = 1 + sinφ0 * (2 * n - sinφ0), ρ0 = Math.sqrt(C) / n;
```

I am trying to laod through IIS. Any working code for this showreel example ?

And is there any way to make these graphs vertical Instead of horizontal?

And Instead of loading local files If I load directly from given url's

then these 3 below URLs are returning 404 error, any code for these 3 files ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.csv.js?2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.time.js?2.3.0"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the character set, i.e. `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need d3.csv.js, d3.layout.js & d3.time.js seperately anymore. Just download the d3.v2.js or the latest d3.v3.js from d3js.org site and remove the above three lines as they are calls to a location that doesn't exist anymore.

Try opening http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.time.js?2.3.0 in the browser and it will return a 404 error

But if you try http://mbostock.github.io/d3/d3.v2.js?2.3.0 it returns the file (Like its supposed to)